# $12$ hour digit clock probability problem

Tags: probability

Consider a $12$ hour digital clock (one that takes values from $00:00$ to $11:59$). Look at it at a random point during a 12 hour period.

a) What is the probability that you see at least one digit taking the value $1$?

b)What is the probability that you see exactly one digit taking the value $1$?

This is my solution, I would like confirmation on my results.

a) We can have

$$a:01 \text{ for }a\in \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11\}$$
$$a:1b \text{ for }a\in \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11\}, b\in \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$$
$$a:c1 \text{ for }a\in \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11\}, c\in \{2,3,4,5\}$$
$$01:d \text{ where } |d|=60-15=45$$
$$10:d \text{ where } |d|=60-15=45$$
$$11:d \text{ where } |d|=60-15=45$$
Therefore
$$P(\text{at least one digit }1)=\frac{12\times 15+3\times45}{60\times12}=\frac{7}{16}=0.4375$$

b) We can have

$$a:01 \text{ for }a\in \{0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$$
$$a:1b \text{ for }a\in \{0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}, b\in \{0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$$
$$a:c1 \text{ for }a\in \{0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}, c\in \{2,3,4,5\}$$
$$01:d \text{ where } |d|=60-15=45$$
$$10:d \text{ where } |d|=60-15=45$$
Therefore
$$P(\text{exactly one digit 1})=\frac{9\times14+2\times45}{60\times12}=\frac{3}{10}=0.3$$

Comment: I don't understand your notation, but your final answers are correct.

Comment: since description of the solution is very sparse, I am not sure about calculation for solution to part a) ; There I think the second term in numerator should be 3×60 rather that current 3×45. No.?? What is that **01:d where |d|=60−15=45** about ?